# Comando LaTeX para criar arquivo C

Tags: latex

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de gerar um arquivo a partir do PDF elaborado em LaTeX.

O que eu quero fazer:
Escrevo um código LaTeX, compilo e gero o PDF dele. Em determinado momento, quero mostrar um código que é longo demais para ficar dentro do PDF(questão de legibilidade) e então clico em um nome(Por exemplo: "TratamentoDeDados.c") e então cria-se um arquivo "TratamentoDeDados.c" na mesma pasta do PDF para a pessoa abrir, ver, compilar e testar. O clicar no nome é semelhante ao dado por referências, que abre um link externo(url) ou vai para determinada parte do PDF.

Isso evita o PDF ficar poluído com muito código(3 páginas seguidas) e enviar arquivos .rar ou .zip com o PDF e diversos códigos dentro.

Caso não seja possível criar arquivo, como faz para abri-lo com o clicar no nome, no caso de eu enviar um zip com PDF e códigos dentro?

Comment: Já ouviu falar de listing? Ou do algorithm2e?

Comment: Ouvi falar de listing através do link abaixo. No caso é interessante para pequenos códigos. Mas não ouvi falar do algorithm2e, vou dar uma olhada. http://latexbr.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/dica-mostrando-codigo-c-java-etc-no.html

Comment: Vê se essa listagem na página 29 tá grande o suficiente para você: https://www.dropbox.com/s/be4lg8p48rqrp2m/mono_final.pdf?dl=0 ; acho que é a maior listagem que já fiz em LaTeX

Comment: Nesse link, eu usei uma customização própria do algorithm2e, porém eu perdi esse arquivo customizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}`

Então: `\href{filename.c}{texto do link}` no corpo do texto.

Pesquise sobre Hyperref do Latex para mais informações.

---

Neste caso, você deve distribuir o arquivo junto com o PDF. O latex não vai criá-lo, somente criar o link para a pessoa clicar.